# how to edit polygon using Edit.poly.js in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Requirements: Using Leaflet js maps,

when user a draw polygon with given coordinates without using draw tool and i can also edit that polygon using Edit.poly.js. but  i will not get newly Coordinates.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about what you are trying to do? Do you want to have users draw polygon and get the co-ordinates of its points or just edit an existing polygon or something else?

Comment: Requirements: Using Leaflet js maps,

when user a draw polygon with given coordinates without using draw tool and i can also edit that polygon using Edit.poly.js. but  i will not get newly Coordinates.

Comment: Thank u for your valuable Information.......

Comment: If my answer helped please mark it as correct. Or if your code above is the answer you were looking for an you arrived at it on your own please put it as an answer and mark it as correct so other people can find it :)

Comment: <code is..><br/>  < polygon.on('edit', function (event) { pos = polygon.getLatLngs(); $("#ide").val(getc(pos)); }); });function getc(pos) { var co = new Array(); var coo=""; for(i=0; i<pos.length; i++) { coordinatesarray=position[i]; var lat=coordinatesarray.lat; var log=co.lng; coo=coo+"["+lat+','+log+"],"; } return coo }>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just need to call `getLatLngs()` on your polygon after the user has edited it. So:

    `var polygon = L.polygon([[51.509, -0.08],
                             [51.503, -0.06],
                             [51.51, -0.047]]).addTo(map);
    var points = polygon.getLatLngs();
    //points = [[51.509, -0.08],
                [51.503, -0.06],
                [51.51, -0.047]]`